# Cannot create multiple text box with different id using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unable create multiple text field dynamically using JavaScript and jQuery. My code is below:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ques">No of questions</label>
      <input name="no_of_question" id="ques" class="form-control" placeholder="no of question" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Questions</label>
        <input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px;" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" onClick="addQuestionField();">
        <input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="minus" id="minus" value="-" onClick="deleteQuestionField();">
      </div>
      <div class="text-left" id="intro-add" style="display:none">
        <input type="button" name="" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" value="Add">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:5px;display:block" id="introBox0" >
      <div>
        <input type="text" style="width: 77.5%;float:left; margin-bottom:5px; margin-right:5px;" class="form-control inptbox0" id="scaleans00" name="labelname" placeholder="Answer" value="">
       <input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px; margin-top:5px; float:left;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="labelminus" id="labelminus" value="-">
        <div class="text-left" id="intro-add" style="display:block">
          <input type="button" name="" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" value="Add" onclick="addMore(0,0)">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <hr>
  </div>
```

Here user will create multiple question section and each question section user has to create multiple field using `add` button and will delete using `minus` button . Each question field should unique id.Suppose in section one there are 3 input field then its `ids` should be like this `scaleans00,scaleans01,scaleans02...`  and for section two these should be `scaleans10,scaleans11,scaleans12...` and so on.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    function addQuestionField() {
      var get = $("#ques").val();
      for (var i = 1; i < get; i++) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="form-group dyn" style="margin-top:5px;display:block" id="introBox'+i+'"><div><input type="text" style="width: 77.5%;float:left; margin-bottom:5px; margin-right:5px;" class="form-control inptbox'+i+'" id="scaleans'+i+'0" name="labelname" placeholder="Answer" value=""><input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px; margin-top:5px; float:left;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="labelminus" id="labelminus" value="-"><div class="text-left" id="intro-add" style="display:block"><input type="button" name="" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" value="Add" onclick="addMore('+i+',0)"></div></div></div><hr>');
      }
    }

    function deleteQuestionField() {
      var textareas = $('#container .dyn');
      if (textareas.length !== 0) {
        textareas.last().remove();
        $('#ques').val(textareas.length - 1);
      }
    }
      function addMore(parent,child){
           var mainDiv='#introBox'+parent;
           $(mainDiv).append('<div><input type="text" style="width: 77.5%;float:left; margin-bottom:5px; margin-right:5px;" class="form-control inptbox'+parent+'" id="scaleans" name="labelname" placeholder="Answer" value="">'+'<input type="button" style="line-height:13px; margin-right:2px; margin-top:5px; float:left;" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="labelminus" id="labelminus" value="-"></div>');
          repopulate(parent);
      }
      function repopulate(k){
          var mainId='.inptbox'+k;
          var j=0;
          $(mainId).each(function(i, e) {
              if(i==0){
                   $(this).attr('id', 'scaleans' + i+j);
                  $(this).next().attr('onClick', function(old, n) {
                       return 'removeThis(' + i + ','+j+')';
                  })
                  $(this).next().attr('id', function(old, n) {
                    return 'labelminus' + i+j;
                 });
              }else{
                  $(this).attr('id', 'scaleans' + i+(j+1));
                  $(this).next().attr('onClick', function(old, n) {
                       return 'removeThis(' + i + ','+(j+1)+')';
                  })
                  $(this).next().attr('id', function(old, n) {
                    return 'labelminus' + i+(j+1);
                 });
              }
          })
      }
      function removeThis(r,t) {
            $("#scaleans" + r+t).remove();
            $("#labelminus" + r+t).remove();
            repopulate();
     }
  </script>
```

Here I can not create as per my requirement. [Here is my full code](https://plnkr.co/edit/fOdW6NnifNl3J5ZP3wEG?p=preview).

Comment: your problem is you are not getting unique Id for each question right? or and also your add and delete field not working properly?

Comment: @Logeshwaran : Yes, thats right. The id should come as per my explanation .

Comment: and yes, the first field  of each section should not conatain any `-` button.

Answer (score 0):

I will be explaining to you what is going on with the current code you have put in Plunker

```
function addQuestionField() {
    var get = $("#ques").val();
      for (var i = 1; i < get; i++) {
```

In Your method addQuestionFiled(), the value retrieved into  get variable is not truthy, if you are not entering any value into the

> number of questions

textfield. Hence the html will not get appended

Fill in the number of question as 2, and then click add it will keeping on appending the html to container div  as the 'var get' will have the value 2 and 'var i' is less than 'var get'